# Dont get any scopes when calling my Azure AD OAuth web api

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, oauth, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

I have a web api, using azure ad oauth authentication. I want my associates´ web sites to be able to use this api to display content on their public website. To clearify: No user should be needing consenting/grant anything and they are anonymous.

I have used [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-devquickstarts-webapi-dotnet) to set up my web api and [this code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-code-samples#web-application-to-web-api) ("Web Application to Web API"->WebApp-WebAPI-OAuth2-AppIdentity-DotNet-code) for my demo client.

The default scope/permission was assigned to client app in azure portal, like so

*The actual problem I trying to solve is my different associates webpages should have different permissions. I was hoping to create different scopes and assign different associates client apps with different scopes and I could check if they for example has update_customer_x-scope.*

[image]

All this "seems" to work ok. I get my authentication token and I am able to get content from the web api. **BUT** I dont get any scopes at all. Reading the [first guide(web api)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-devquickstarts-webapi-dotnet) I see that you should be able to get the default scope by using the code:

```
if (ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/scope").Value == "user_impersonation")
        {/*you have the default scope*/}
```

But I dont find anything here, and no scopes at all. Any clues?

This is the content of the JWT-token, as requested
[image]

Comment: How do you get the access token for the API? If you just use client_credentials flow, there will be no scope, because there is no user interaction. If you used Authorization Code Grant flow, you should be able to see the scope claim.

Comment: Can you share the contents of your access token? Paste the JWT on a site like [this](http://shawntabrizi.com/jwt/).

Comment: @astaykov: Im not really sure what you mean, but Im using the AquireTokenAsync()-method of the AuthenticationContext-class. /newline/ I thought Authorization Code Grant flow included a grant from the end user. The end users are users of my associates public pages and they should not be needing to login nor consent, but I need different associates(´webpages) to have different permissions anyway.  Is this possible?

Comment: @Shawn Tabrizi: Done, see edited post

Answer (score 1):

The [TodoListController.cs](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-oauth2-appidentity/blob/master/TodoListWebApp/Controllers/TodoListController.cs) from [WebApp-WebAPI-OAuth2-AppIdentity-DotNet](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-oauth2-appidentity) just use the client credentials flow as astaykov commented for retrieving the access token without user interaction, at this time, if you decode your code via https://jwt.io/, you would not find the `scp` property.

For your requirement, you need to follow [WebApp-WebAPI-OpenIDConnect-DotNet](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect) for calling a web API with the signed-in user's permissions.

Comment: Ok... The end users are just visitors on my associates public webpage, they dont log in, nor should they consent. But different associates should have different permissions, I was hoping to solve this by giving different client applications different setups of scopes,